# Error: name is not defined - Recursive function in class

Tags: python, mergesort

I am still learning Python, and most errors I receive have been syntactical at this point, though I am now receiving an error that reads

> NameError: name 'mergeSort' is not defined

I can't seem to understand why when called outside of the class, the method works, though once I include it in the class the function breaks.

```
class MergeStringList(list):

    def add(self, item):
        self.append(item)

    def mergeSort(self):
        print("Splitting ",self)
        if len(self)>1:
            mid = len(self)//2
            lefthalf = self[:mid]
            righthalf = self[mid:]

            mergeSort(lefthalf)
            mergeSort(righthalf)

            i=0
            j=0
            k=0

            while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
                if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                    self[k]=lefthalf[i]
                    i=i+1
                else:
                    self[k]=righthalf[j]
                    j=j+1
                    k=k+1

            while i < len(lefthalf):
                self[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
                k=k+1

            while j < len(righthalf):
                self[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
                k=k+1
        print("Merging ",self)

    def printList(self):
        print(self)

mergeList = MergeStringList()
mergeList.add("stitch")
mergeList.add("daily")
mergeList.add("blade")
mergeList.printList()
mergeList.mergeSort()
mergeList.printList()
```

Comment: Because they are methods on the class; you would need to call `self.mergeSort`. I doubt that would work though, you would probably need to instantiate new MergeStringList objects for each half and call their `mergeSort` methods. I'm not sure why you've done this as a class in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel. This was exactly what I needed to do. SN: This is a homework assignment and unfortunately is a requirement to make it a class despite the redundant nature.

Answer (score 0):

Recurse calls require to invoked on the object i.e. `self.mergeSort`. Change these two lines:

`mergeSort(lefthalf)
mergeSort(righthalf)`

Update:

To make the code functional you should also, change the method signature since, it doesn't accept arguments right now. That is,

`def mergeSort(self, input)`

Comment: I have actually tried each of those and after doing so I get another error. **TypeError: mergeSort() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Comment: Ofcouse, since you don't have an argument to pass the list `lefthalf` and `righthalf`. You should change the method signature to something like this: `mergeSort(self, input)`